# Calling multiple methods as parameter of a php function

Tags: php, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I got this function:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static function make_table( $inputList, $funcArray ,$fieldArray){
        $i = 0;
        $result = Array();
        foreach($inputList as $element){
            $j = 0;
            foreach($funcArray as $function){
                $result[$i][$fieldArray[$j]] = $element->$function();
                $j++;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $result;  
    }
```

where inputList is a list of Ticket_Reply items (which contain an instance variable of class ticket_content.) funcArray is the list of functions to perform.

//////////////////////////////////////////
I execute it like this:

```
$result['ticket_replies'] = make_table($entire_ticket['reply_array'], Array("getTReplyId","getContent()->getContent","getTimestamp"), Array("tReplyId","replyContent","timestamp"));
```

**What I try to do when passing getContent()->getContent, is execute getContent of the Ticket_Reply object, which returns a ticket_content object and then perform getContent on that returned object to return the text representing the content.**

//////////////////////////////////////////
// if I execute this with function array

```
Array("getTReplyId","getContent()","getTimestamp")
```

instead of

```
Array("getTReplyId","getContent()->getContent","getTimestamp")
```

then my output found by print_r :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [tReplyId] => 1 [replyContent] => Ticket_Content Object ( [tContentId:Ticket_Content:private] => 1 [content:Ticket_Content:private] => ik krijg het spel niet installed! [db] => Array ( [host] => localhost [port] => 3306 [name] => ryzom_ams_lib [user] => root [pass] => xxxxxx ) ) [timestamp] => 2013-07-08 14:47:19 ) [1] => Array ( [tReplyId] => 5 [replyContent] => Ticket_Content Object ( [tContentId:Ticket_Content:private] => 5 [content:Ticket_Content:private] => Help he got hacked! [db] => Array ( [host] => localhost [port] => 3306 [name] => ryzom_ams_lib [user] => root [pass] => xxxxxx ) ) [timestamp] => 2013-07-09 00:48:17 ) )
```

As you can see the replyContent is an object of class ticke_content, and the class ticket_content provides a function getContent, So I would guess that getContent()->getContent in the $funcArray would execute the getContent of the object, but instead it gives the warning:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Ticket_Reply::getContent()->getContent()
```

where Ticket_Reply is the name of the class of the actual objects of the inputList

---

now someone already told me to use call_user_func_array, which I tried, but not with much success.

> ```
> public static function make_table( $inputList, $funcArray ,$fieldArray){
>     $i = 0; 
>     $result = Array();
>     foreach($inputList as $element){
>         $j = 0;
>         foreach($funcArray as $function){
>             $result[$i][$fieldArray[$j]] = call_user_func_array(array_merge(array($element), $function),array());
>             $j++;
>         }
>         $i++;
>     }
>     return $result;  
> }
> ```

with the params :

```
make_table($entire_ticket['reply_array'], Array(Array("getTReplyId"),Array("getContent", "getContent"),Array("getTimestamp")), Array("tReplyId","replyContent","timestamp"));
```

Though there is a warning:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members
```

and they don't return the correct result. Is it actually possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to call a variable as a function, that contents of that variable have to be a valid function name (that is, just the actual *name* of the function, and none of the punctuation that may go with it, such as `()` or `->`).  As such:

`"getContent"` will work, but

`"getContent()->getContent"` will not.

The simplest (but POTENTIALLY VERY INSECURE) way to do this would be to use eval() instead, with this line here:

```
$result[$i][$fieldArray[$j]] = eval("{$element}->{$function}()");
```

Just to give some idea of precisely how harmful it could be if someone could slip an arbitrary string in there; imagine $element is `"system("/bin/rm -rf /"); //"` (hopefully you're not running your web server as root, but my point should be clear). :)

If you do this, make *absolutely sure* you check the values in $element and $function.  If they aren't valid function names (that is, if they contain anything other than numbers, letters, and underscores), error out.

If you want to be safer but more complicated (probably a good idea), you can do something like this pseudocode in your inner loop:

```
$fnames = explode('->', $function);
$intermediate_result = NULL;
foreach($fnames as $fname) {
  if($fname ends with '()') {
    if($intermediate_result != NULL) {
      $intermediate_result = $fname();
    } else {
      $intermediate_result = $intermediate_result->$fname();
    }
  } else {
    if($intermediate_result != NULL) {
      $intermediate_result = $fname();
    } else {
      $intermediate_result = $intermediate_result->$fname();
    }
  }
}

$result[$i][$fieldArray[$j]] = $intermediate_result;
```

(Note: This is pseudocode and I haven't tested it, but I believe it ought to work and it should be safer than calling eval.)

Answer (score 0):

This statement appears to be the issue:

`call_user_func_array(array_merge(array($element), $function),array());`

`call_user_func_array()` expects your function as the first param and then an array of the function arguments second. It appears your your trying to merge a few things together, including the return of the function. I'm not sure how it is supposed to be structured but possibly like:

```
$result[$i][$fieldArray[$j]] = array_merge(array($element),call_user_func_array($function,array()));
```